# Change note names

Tags: songs

In Germany and Scandinavia it is common to use H instead of B (natural). However, b-flat is still written as Bb and not Hb. Is this possible in the `Songs` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}  %change between chorded, lyric, slides, rawtext
\notenamesin{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
\notenamesout{A}{H}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Test}[]
\beginverse
\[A]A, \[B&]Bb, \[B]H, \[C]C
\endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't b-flat be written just as B in this context?

Comment: No, B-flat will be written as Bb (however, to make the confusion conplete, it will be pronounced as B). B-natural would be written as H.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the package allows you to use whatever letters you choose, even if those letters are not originally defined as a note. Therefore, there is no need to adjust the default set-up or to convert the input and output using `\notenamesin` and `\notenamesout`. You can just straightforwardly type in what you want to get out and do the following (some nonsensical notes added on purpose):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}  %change between chorded, lyric, slides, rawtext

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Test}[]
\beginverse
\[A]A, \[B&]Bb, \[H]H, \[C]C, \[B]B, \[H&]Hb, \[X&]X
\endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

With the output being:

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution so far. However, the only problem is that it doesn't work with transposing.

Answer (score 2):

When using note-name conversion, use braces to suppress name conversion: `\[{B}&]`.

[image: Using braces]

Alternatively, a chord name can take arbitrary text or macro code.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}  %change between chorded, lyric, slides, rawtext
\notenamesin{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
\notenamesout{A}{H}{C}{D}{E}{F}{SOL}
\newcommand\Bflat{B\flt}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Test}[]
\beginverse
\[A]A, \[\Bflat]{\Bflat macro}, \[B]B=H, \[C]C, \[G]G, \[B&]{\Bflat}, \[{B}&]\ \ \llap{\{B\}\&}
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, since it doesn't work with transposing either, I think @Jasper's solution is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it that was:

- `\notnames` works
- there is some strange problem with placement and alignement

First, I dropped your chords and used a copy from the manual. To make the change more evident, I put the in two columns.

Second, while trying to make things run I ended up with this in Texmaker:

- compile as `pdflatex`
- had to disable `\inputenc` and `babel`
- tried influencing the alignment effect without success by disabling `[chorded]` and `geometry`, and adding song-info: the text simply is set too much to the left

[image: example with and without notenames]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
%\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{songs}
%\usepackage[chorded]{songs}  %change between chorded, lyric, slides, rawtext
\notenamesin{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
\notenamesout{A}{H}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}

\begin{document}

\songsection{Tests}
\begin{songs}{}
    \beginsong{Test - with names}[by={me}]
        \beginverse% from manual, for reference
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav’n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
        \endverse
    \endsong
    
\nextcol% <<<

    \beginsong{Test2 - Standard}[by={me}]
        \beginverse
        \notenames

 \[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav’n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
        \endverse
    \endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not fully clear to me how this answers the question to be honest.

Comment: A problem could have been that the translation is faulty. It's not. // I had your solution in mind, but decided to stick to the manual, which should work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem. The problem is that I wan't to write H for B-natural, but Bb for B-flat. This can't be done directly with `\notenames`

Comment: Ok, why not writing one or two simple macros using \newcommand to do that?

Comment: I guess this is @cicada's solution. However, I can't figure out how to do that, if transposing should still work